# Bug when trying to pull a random quote from an array.

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to display a random quote from an array using random number generator and I'm getting an error and unsure why. Here is what I have. I know this might be a repeat but I feel that it should be printing but its not. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment 9</title> 
    <link href="images/avatar.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png">
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<aside>
</aside>
<div id="main">
<h1> Arrays and Coditional Statements</h1>

<h2> Quote of the Day</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var quote= ["It's not the size of the dog in the fight, It's the size of the fight in the dog",
"Love is the one thing that transcends time and space", "When it rains it pours", "Wake up slow", 
" Do not go gentle into that good night; Old age should burn and rave at close of day. Rage, rage against the dying of the light."
];


var randquote= quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length)];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=randquote;
}
</script>




</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're never calling `myFunction()`.

Comment: Yep - [works](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/WQYeZg) if you actually call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `myFunction()` your code works perfectly:

```js
function myFunction(){
var quote= ["It's not the size of the dog in the fight, It's the size of the fight in the dog",
"Love is the one thing that transcends time and space", "When it rains it pours", "Wake up slow", 
" Do not go gentle into that good night; Old age should burn and rave at close of day. Rage, rage against the dying of the light."
];


var randquote= quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length)];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=randquote;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Another way to do it (A bit cleaner):

```js
(function (){
    var quote= [
        "It's not the size of the dog in the fight, It's the size of the fight in the dog",
        "Love is the one thing that transcends time and space",
        "When it rains it pours",
        "Wake up slow", 
        "Do not go gentle into that good night; Old age should burn and rave at close of day. Rage, rage against the dying of the light."
    ];


    var randquote= quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length)];

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=randquote;
})();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```